# Keymap of my addon gets lost after restart (solved)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've scripted 4 custom pie menus for my own workflow and put them in one .py file including individual keymaps (A,S,D,Alt+A). The menus work fine and when I import the addon (prefs, install addon, choose the .py file and activate), everything works (pie menus pop up on key press). But once I restart Blender, the keymaps are gone and the menus won't show up. They (and the custom operators i defined in the same file) are still registered though, since I can call them with the command line even after restarting Blender.

The registration code looks like this (whole thing would 300+ lines):

```
addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MMA)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MMS)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MMD)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MMAltA)
    
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    
    if kc:
        akm = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal', space_type='EMPTY')
        akmi = akm.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "A", "PRESS", ctrl = False, shift = False).properties.name="LHO_MT_MMA"
        addon_keymaps.append((akm, akmi))
        skm = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal', space_type='EMPTY')
        skmi = skm.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "S", "PRESS", ctrl = False, shift = False).properties.name="LHO_MT_MMS"
        addon_keymaps.append((skm, skmi))
        dkm = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal', space_type='EMPTY')
        dkmi = dkm.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "D", "PRESS", ctrl = False, shift = False).properties.name="LHO_MT_MMD"
        addon_keymaps.append((dkm, dkmi))
        altakm = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal', space_type='EMPTY')
        altakmi = skm.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "A", "PRESS", ctrl = False, shift = False, alt = True).properties.name="LHO_MT_MMAltA"
        addon_keymaps.append((altakm, altakmi))
```

I am using 2.91. The code worked in 2.81. I am kind of lost now since i tried both the keymapping from blender templates and what i found online.

The keys are not used in my keymap, since i only want to use them for my menus.

EDIT: Fixed it myself by a lot of trial and error. I cant say for certain, what the problem was, but now it works with this:

```
addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MMA)
    
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc=wm.keyconfigs.addon
    
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        akmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', type = 'A', value = 'PRESS', ctrl = False, shift = False).properties.name="LHO_MT_MMA"
        addon_keymaps.append((km, akmi))
```

Comment: Preferable if you create an answer as an answer rather than editing question and marking it as "solved".